# convert cable modem to connect to a phone jack?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, modem, cable, phone

I have an older cable modem and router. They work. I moved to a new place and the internet service is through the phone line.

Is there any way, an adapter or something, that will allow me to connect my cable modem to the phone jack?

I’d just rather not buy a new modem if there’s a way to use the one I have.

Comment: No, there is no such adapter.  Consult with the ISP on the other end of that phone jack for modem requirements (e.g. ADSL service).

Comment: FWIW, in addition to what @sawdust says about you not being able to use your old cable modem, if you have thrift stores near you I am pretty sure you can find a modem that will work with your ISP that doesn’t cost too much. Heck, here in NYC people just put this stuff in front of their buildings at times if they switch ISPs or just move. Check local listings on Craigslist and Facebook marketplace as well.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, the technology for doing broadband Internet service over phone lines (DSL) is completely different from the technology for doing broadband Internet service over cable TV coax lines (DOCSIS).

They're completely different kinds of modems and share very little in common.